# ASP Chart with multiple X axis columns

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an SQL table with two columns, salesperson and status. The status can be one of three things, gold, silver and bronze.

How do I go about creating a chart where the salesperson name appears once along the x-axis but has three columns above their name for a count of each status?

Thanks,
Jonno

Comment: Have you tried ASP CHARTS control

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to do something like this post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx

You can also try this example:

```
double[] array1 = { 2.8, 4.4, 6.5, 8.3, 3.6, 5.6, 7.3 };
double[] array2 = { 2.0, 4.0, 6.1, 7.8, 2.5, 5.0, 6.2 };

chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
chtStudentResult.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindY(array1);
chtStudentResult.Series.Add("Series2");
chtStudentResult.Series["Series2"].Points.DataBindY(array2);
```

It would create a chart like this [image]

Comment: I understand the example you've displayed there but can't seem to work out how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: The key is understanding how to format your data source to display what you want. There are [walkthroughs](http://help.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument6597) out there that can help you with specific scenarios. But I'd need to understand your data better to give specific instruction. Can you expand your question, and show how your data is stored? Is salesperson a uid in the table?