# ASP Chart. Multiple X axis values

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, axis

I have been trying to have a chart with horizontal bars, with 2 series, one of them has huge values (1000,5000) and the other one tends to have smaller ones (10,100).

Something like this but on horizontal:
[ASP Chart with multiple X axis columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318775/asp-chart-with-multiple-x-axis-columns)

The problem is that I'm unable to have some kind of different range/legend for each one.
The small one stays small, but I would like to have some kind of proportional, having 2 legends on bottom.

How could I do that?

I have tried different things like using this statement:

```
    seriesSmall.XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Maximum = 200
```

But it did not work out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
seriesSmall.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
```