# C# chart control populate with stored procedure with parameters

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, charts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKrFb.jpg)I can populate chart control in C# Winforms with stored procedures without parameters and that's fine. But now I need to use stored procedure with parameters. Any advice how to do that?

Below is my code how i am populating chart control with stored procedure without parameters.

```
sqlCon.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter("[Proc1]", sqlCon);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
myCommand.Fill(ds);

DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
chart1.DataSource = source;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Pojazd";
chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Suma";

chart1.DataBind();
```

Please help me :-)

Comment: It's similar to passing parameterized query as in `cmd.Parameters.Add()`

Comment: I tryed but it didn't work.

Comment: I am not sure if DataSet is correct object in this case...

Comment: what didn't work?..Error, anything?

Comment: None error. Just no chart is displaying

Comment: use the `try-catch` block.

Comment: Are any records in the DataSource?

Comment: I already have try catch block but no error is catching. It seems like everything goes ok but no result set is returning... any idea what else?

Comment: What do you mean records in DataSource? How to check it?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see if it's being populated with the data you want from the database. That way you know if the command is working correctly.

Comment: I did it and i see that my dataSource has all needed data from sql. It looks like only displaying is not working...

Comment: I would rather bind to a series than the whole chart-

Answer (score 0):

Just a further explanation of what @Rakitić said.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PARAMNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar,10).Value = paramValue;
```

Then you'll need to add this parameter within your stored procedure. Which I'm just guessing you're using Sql Server:

```
@PARAMNAME varchar(10)
```

Comment: Nope. Still nothing is displaying:

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? From your image and sample code it looks like you have already mapped your X/Y axis with data. Are you trying to add more data to your X-axis? If so you may need to add a AxisType.Secondary if that's the case, as shown here in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724464/asp-chart-multiple-x-axis-values

Comment: Ok I did it. The problem was that to wide range of data was requested by the procedure and the chart wasn't able to display so huge amount of data. Thank you for your help :)